# Which software to put two wifi connection together? (Linux)

Tags: linux, wifi, connection-speed

I've two Wi-Fi adapters:

1. Built in adapter - Quallcom Atheros. It is connected to router1 and gives approximately 350 kb/s.
2. External adapter - Ralink. It is connected to router2 and gives approximately 300 kb/s.

Which software would help me to get them together? I mean my speed would be 350 + 300 = 650 kb/s.

Comment: Are these two separate internet connections, or do paths to the two routers converge to a point that has a single public IP address?

Comment: [Meta discussion about this question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/setting-the-boundary-between-software-recommendations-and-setup-how-to). You're more likely to get answers on [unix.se] than here; we can migrate this question there if you want (do not repost). Either way, you need to clarify whether what you want is to split traffic between two different internet connections, or to aggregate two local links that converge to a single public IP address: the answers will be completely different.

Comment: @Gilles, let's say different routers with different IP adresses. It is my neighbor's modem.

Comment: @Mawg, they did suggest my topic to be duplicate of these: 
1) http://superuser.com/questions/239546/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-internet-connections-to-increase-performance
2) http://superuser.com/questions/456328/how-to-bond-two-different-internet-connections?lq=1
3) http://superuser.com/questions/363843/if-i-have-two-internet-connections-on-osx-how-can-i-use-both-to-increase-my-ban?lq=1
4) http://www.wikihow.com/Combine-Two-Internet-Connections

These may help you :)